# where does uname get version number in FreeBSD RELEASE?

Tags: freebsd

I installed FreeBSD 9.1-RELEASE, after binary upgrading to 9.2-RELEASE using freebsd-update, all files I checked are correctly in 9.2-RELEASE-p4.  For example:

1. the kernel contains the new version:

   ```
   # strings /boot/kernel/kernel | grep RELEASE|grep 9
   @(#)FreeBSD 9.2-RELEASE-p4 #0: Tue Apr  8 18:08:22 UTC 2014
   FreeBSD 9.2-RELEASE-p4 #0: Tue Apr  8 18:08:22 UTC 2014
   9.2-RELEASE-p4
   ```
2. the first line of /etc/hosts shows it is upgraded to 9.2:

   ```
   # $FreeBSD: release/9.2.0/etc/hosts 109997 2003-01-28 21:29:23Z dbaker $
   ```

I asked on another forum and have verified that:

1. I never compiled kernel, and do not have /usr/src and /usr/obj folders.
2. the default /etc/profile is unchanged, in particular I never defined UNAME_* vars .
3. I also tried "unsetenv UNAME_r"

However, uname somehow shows the wrong version 9.1:

```
# uname -a
FreeBSD localhost.localdomain 9.1-RELEASE FreeBSD 9.1-RELEASE #0 r243825: Tue Dec  4 09:23:10 UTC 2012     root at farrell.cse.buffalo.edu:/usr/obj/usr/src/sys/GENERIC  amd64
```

So where does uname get the version number from?  Which file(s) might not have been upgraded?  Thank you!

Comment: `uname` shows the properties of the running kernel, did you skip the reboot after upgrading?

Comment: certainly not, the machine has reboot dozens of times afterwards.

Answer (score 5):

*FreeBSD* `uname` is using `sysctl` values to fill-in its output, so there is no file to update except for the kernel.

Here are the corresponding `sysctl` key to `uname` options (from **usr.bin/uname/uname.c**):

- `-i` : *kern.ident*
- `-m` : *hw.machine*
- `-n` : *kern.hostname*
- `-p` : *hw.machine_arch*
- `-r` : *kern.osrelease*
- `-s` or `-o` : *kern.ostype*
- `-v` : *kern.version*

It seems your actual kernel is not the one you think. You can check the kernel file in use with:

```
# sysctl kern.bootfile
```

Comment: Thanks, but "sysctl kern.bootfile" does return "kern.bootfile: /boot/kernel/kernel", which contains the string "9.2-RELEASE-p4", yet uname claims "9.1-RELEASE".

Comment: What about a massive search for "9.1-RELEASE" to maybe found out where this come from? (ie `find / -type f -exec grep -l "9.1-RELEASE" {} \;`)

Comment: ok, this is something you do only when being pushed :-)  I just did what you suggested above, looks like comments here don't support line breaks, hopefully I can write the result clearly (how do you do formatting above?). The result include: /etc/motd, /usr/local/bin/Xorg, /usr/local/sbin/lsof, some under /usr/ports, /var/db/locate.database, /var/log/gdm/:0.log, /var/log/Xorg.0.log, /var/run/dmesg.boot, /var/log/dmesg.today.

Comment: looks like I may be indeed running 9.1 kernel, as dmesg also says FreeBSD 9.1-RELEASE #0. But, I can not find a kernel bearing that. "find /boot | xargs grep 9.1-RELEASE" retuns nothing. "find /boot | xargs grep 9.2-RELEASE" returns /boot/kernel/kernel and /boot/kernel.old/kernel .